# Exception when attaching entity with navigation properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, many-to-many

I've got entities `Exhibit` and `Exhibition`, which are in many-to-many relationship. `Exhibit` also can have many categories.

```
public class ExhibitionModel
{
    public ExhibitionModel()
    {
        this.Exhibits = new List<ExhibitModel>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int ExhibitionId { get; set; }

    //some props

    public virtual IList<ExhibitModel> Exhibits { get; set; }
}

public class ExhibitModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ExhibitId { get; set; }

    //some props

    public virtual IList<CategoryModel> Categories { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<ExhibitionModel> Exhibitions { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryModel
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<ExhibitModel> Exhibits { get; set; }
}
```

When I'm creating a new exhibition, in my ViewModel I've got all Exhibition parameters and string, which contains selected exhibits ids.

```
    public ActionResult Create(CreateExhibitionViewModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ExhibitsString))
                {
                    model.Exhibition.AddExhibitsToModel(model.ExhibitsString, exhibitsRepo);
                }

                var result = exhibitionsRepo.Create(model.Exhibition);
                if (result != null)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
            return View(model);
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }

    public static void AddExhibitsToModel(this ExhibitionModel model, string exhibitsString, ExhibitsRepository exhibitsRepo)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(exhibitsString))
        {
            string[] ids = exhibitsString.Split(',');
            foreach (string stringId in ids)
            {
                int id;
                ExhibitModel exhibit = new ExhibitModel();
                if (int.TryParse(stringId, out id))
                {
                    exhibit = exhibitsRepo.Read(id);
                }

                model.Exhibits.Add(exhibit);
            }
        }
    }
```

And `Create` method from `ExhibitionRepository`

```
    public ExhibitionModel Create(ExhibitionModel exhibition)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var dbContext = new MuseumContext())
            {
                foreach (var exhibit in exhibition.Exhibits)
                {
                    if (exhibit.ExhibitId != 0 && dbContext.Entry(exhibit).State == EntityState.Detached)
                    {
                        dbContext.Exhibits.Attach(exhibit);
                    }
                }

                var result = dbContext.Exhibitions.Add(exhibition);
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
                return result;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I'm attaching every exhibit entity to avoid creating new records. And when two exhibits have the same category, attaching second exhibit throws exception

> Attaching an entity of type 'Project.Models.CategoryModel' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

What should I do to fix this problem?

Regards,
Konrad

Answer (score 0):

This error usually happens when the entity is already tracked by EF. I guess it might be here:

```
exhibit = exhibitsRepo.Read(id);
```

You have two options.

1. You can set the Read method with [AsNoTracking()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).
   Maybe `db.Exhibits.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.Id== id);`

   This way you explicitly tell EF to not to track the entity.
2. If the Exhibits are already in the database, by just adding them to the Exhibition collection and saving the changes, EF should make and save the reference for you (in the exhibits records).
   There is no need to re-attach the entity.